# showing different currency for sidebar block

Tags: currency

I've set up two store in CAD and USD. Now it has problem when I am on CAD the price are showing CAD but best seller and sales product block at left side bar are showing USD. And when I changed it to USD, left side bar are showing CAD but products list and product detail show USD price.
How to fix this problem?
Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

First confirm where the file is located for left sidebar using templates path hint then, check the price code:

$finalPrice is the variable that contain your price add this code where price is show.

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```